# What happens to a ghoul's learned discipline if embraced as a thin-blood?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade-5e

Let's suppose that a 13th generation vampire has embraced a ghoul who has learned the first point of her master's primary discipline. This would make her a thin-blood. In this particular situation, what would happen?

Should the thin-blood gain Discipline Affinity as a bonus thin-blood merit? Must Discipline Affinity be one of her initial thin-blood merits? Does she lose the use of the discipline? Should I drop a meteor on the character that did it?

---

related question: [Can a thin-blood learn a discipline with the help of a non-thin-blood vampire?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/150666/can-a-thin-blood-learn-a-discipline-with-the-help-of-a-non-thin-blood-vampire)

Comment: I use she for the ghoul because the actual ghoul that make me think of it is a girl

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The V:tM 5th Edition core rules explain that, unlike in prior editions, the ability of a ghoul to manifest the first dot (and an associated first-rank power) of their domitor is not a permanent change. Instead, it's something that lasts for about a month after drinking that blood. (p.234) Since that blood will be drained from the ghoul in the process of the Embrace, there's no need to worry about that potential discipline — an embraced ghoul is simply treated as an ordinary vampire of its type. No extra power, and no additional limitations.